# close menu toggle after click link

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I'm having one problem is:
I've one javascript running on all pages and I want to keep it active even if you change pages inside of the website (not refresh) but the problem is that I've one menu toggle and every time that I changed the page, the script starts again. so I changed my code menu and added an attribute to link `rel="history"`.
After doing that, the script works without interrupts, but every time I click on the menu link, the menu toggle doesn't close... remains open when I change the page. and cannot know why. anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

```
<a class="toggle-menu">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</a>

<div class="menu-drawer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="main" rel="history">main</a></li>
    <li><a href="press" rel="history">Press</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts" rel="history">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  $(".toggle-menu").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('.menu-drawer').toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: `</li></li>` is invalid HTML markup

Comment: Where is exactly `.toggle-menu` in your [mcve]? Please [edit] your question to include the minimal **valid** HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: Suggestion: to preserve a state after page refresh: learn about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm sorry! I already edited my question and added my `.toogle-menu`! Thank you!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm building this website in cargo collectives's platform. They have their own storage and links doesnt start with www.